# Trigger Xcode notification after certain time has passed (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, time, notifications, alert

I've tried a lot of things but I just can't seem to figure out which command to use to trigger an alert in (example) 2 days, or 5 hours. Can anyone help me out? What I'd like to be able to do is the following:

```
var number = 3
var repeat = day
*Code with 'number' and 'repeat' in it.*
```

So in this case it would send out an alert in 3 days. Anyone here knows how to do that? ^^

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try searching on google for tutorials first. Here is an example: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250

Comment: I tried but couldn't really figure it out.. Will take a look at it, thanks! :)

Comment: Actually you say "send out an alert", so you want to send something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/h4ph9mk.jpg)?

Comment: @paper1111 that is correct, but then only when some countdown hits zero :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, place this on the top of the file that needs notifications:

```
import UserNotifications
```

Then place this in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` of `AppDelegate`

```
let notifCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
notifCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options, completionHandler: nil)
```

So now request the Notification as follows:

```
// timeInterval is in seconds, so 60*60*12*3 = 3 days, set repeats to true if you want to repeat the trigger
let requestTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (60*60*12*3), repeats: false)

let requestContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
requestContent.title = "Title"        // insert your title
requestContent.subtitle = "Subtitle"  // insert your subtitle
requestContent.body = "A body in notification." // insert your body
requestContent.badge = 1 // the number that appears next to your app
requestContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

// Request the notification 
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "PutANameForTheNotificationHere", content: requestContent, trigger: requestTrigger)

// Post the notification!
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
    if let error = error {
        // do something to the error
    } else {
        // posted successfully, do something like tell the user that notification was posted
    }
}
```

This part of code does three things:

1. Define the trigger
2. Create the notification context
3. Post the context

If you intend to continue to work with notifications, look at [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250), which also talks about how to react when the user taps on your notification.

---

Note: `UNMutableNotificationContext` is mutable, despite the name, `UN` is just the namespace. Don't get confused!

---

[image: Notification]

If you provide a subtitle, it will be between the title and body.

---

This is the `badge` property:

[image]

Comment: You are amazing, thank you very much! I'll test this out in a few and mark this question as answered if it is, thanks! :D